# ListView scroll clicked item to center of the ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In my application i have an horizontal `listview` where it contains 20 to 30 items, in `listview` it is showing 5 item, and when i click any item (accept first two and last two items) it should move to center of the `listview` how can i do that please help thanks in advance

Comment: show your codes please

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar can u just tell me the logic.. if it is possible

Comment: what you want really ? when you click any item you want to go to center of listview?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar ya the selected item should move to center in `listview`

Comment: for example , there are 10 items, when you click 1.item then you want to 1.item goes to 5. it is right?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar ya, actually in `listview` there are 20 items AND 5 items are visible if i  click the 4th item it should move to center. and if i click 5th, 6th so on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50766/discussion-between-wizard-and-ersin-gulbahar)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like ;

1. In your arraylist (or list what you use) you change the order. I mean if you click **1.item** you should reorder with replace your 1.item to middle of the item.
2. Then you can set your **adapter** again.
3. Then you can set your list (list.adapter)
4. Then you can `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
5. Then you can  `list.setSelection(index);`

Comment: no i don't want like this when item is clicked the clicked item should scroll to center.

Comment: what you mean with saying scroll to center, item go to center of the list then you can set your   `setSelection`  I edit my answer

Comment: @Wizard can you try this